Link provided when answer is automatically converted into a comment should mention the feature and its triggers
As per title, the page linked to when an answer is automatically converted into a comment doesn't mention automatic conversion of answers into comments.
This feature may be helpful, but it unexpectedly deviates from the user's initial intention.
I suggest the informational resource (linked page) should explain:

How the feature works (e.g. what triggers it)
How best to progress and improve the answer in the event of a potential false-positive


This is universal, and called trivial answer

@MetaAndrewT. good find. The top response says: "which we'll be updating with a brief explanation of what happens when an answer is converted to a comment" - looks like they may not have got around to that yet.
